# XGBoost Model in AWS-Sagemaker Fails with no error message

Tags: xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to get a model using the XGBoost classifier in AWS-Sagemaker.  I'm following the abalone example, but when I run it to build the training job it states InProgress 3 times and then just states Failed.  Where do I go to find why it failed?

I've double checked the parameters and made sure the input and output files and directories in S3 were correct.  I know there is permission to read and write because when setting up the data for train/validate/test I read and write to S3 with no problems.

```
print(status)
while status !='Completed' and status!='Failed':
    time.sleep(60)
    status = client.describe_training_job(TrainingJobName=job_name)['TrainingJobStatus']
    print(status)
```

That is the code where the print statements come from.  Is there something I can add to receive a better error message?

Comment: The training log is available in CloudWatch Logs. Just go to the AWS console, find your job under 'Training jobs', and scroll down until you see the link to the log. What error do you see there?

Comment: Many times I came across similar problem is because of memory leak. The way to correct is to restart the job with a bigger virtual machine. BTW, I'm using Sagemaker notebook instances.

Comment: @JulienSimon Thanks for helping it was in the logs.  I had the wrong file type sent to the model. I had to change from csv to libsvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred was that the file sent for predictions was csv but the XGBoost settings were set to receive libsvm.